# Node dependencies error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, npm-install

I have a problem with local dependencies. I don't understand how to fix it.

You can see all steps to reproduce my error.

Someone have an idea ? Thank a lot

**Steps to reproduce**

```
$ npm i --prefix module-a
OK
$ npm i --prefix module-b
OK
$ npm i --prefix module-c
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'module-c/node_modules/.staging/...'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'module-c/node_modules/.staging/...'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'module-c/node_modules/.staging/...'
...
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rmdir
npm ERR! path module-c/node_modules/.staging/core-js-pure-7ef16f00
npm ERR! errno -39
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'module-c/node_modules/.staging/core-js-pure-7ef16f00'
```

**Env**

```sh
$ npm -v
6.14.6
$ node -v
v10.22.1
```

**Files**

`module-a/package.json`

```json
{
   "name": "aaa",
   "main": "index.js"
}
```

`module-b/package.json`

```json
{
   "name": "bbb",
   "main": "index.js",
   "dependencies": {
      "aaa": "file:../module-a"
   }
}
```

`module-c/package.json`

```json
{
   "name": "ccc",
   "main": "index.js",
   "dependencies": {
      "aaa": "file:../module-a",
      "bbb": "file:../module-b"
   }
}
```

---

For you information, I have try with `npm link`. This solution work on my dev env but it doesn't work on other environnements because *build* and *run* are executed on 2 differents servers (so *run* server doesn't have `bbb` package in global packages and I have the error `Cannot find package bbb`).

`module-c/package.json`

```json
{
   "name": "ccc",
   "main": "index.js",
   "script": {
      "postinstall": "cd ../module-b && npm link && cd - && npm link bbb"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "aaa": "file:../module-a"
   }
}
```